# python expresiones regulares

Tags: python, regex

Estoy intentando sacar los nif de un fichero de texto con el siguiente formato :

Fichero con.txt

```
texto dkdkkdkdkdk
Expediente
202002345610854
Subvención
Asunto
texto ldllakdkkdkdkdk
dlldlkfkjfkdj
ldldkfjjf
kdkdkdk :
dkdkfjkdk:
Código expediente
DNI/CIF
Importe Subvencion Concedida
1
2020012727
01234567N
1.500,00 €
2
2020013992
76543210Y
1.620,00 €
3
2020013331
01234567T
1.000,00 €
4
2020013637
01234567A
1.500,00 €
5
2020012875
01234567Q
2.220,00 €
6
2020014315
76543210B
1.860,00 €
7
2020012856
76543210Y
1.000,00 €
8
2020013410
76543210D
1.620,00 €
9
2020014320
76543210E
1.120,00 €
10
2020014090
76543210W
1.000,00 €
11
2020012392
76543210Z
1.980,00 €
12
2020012646
76543210S
1.500,00 €
13
2020013292
76543210K
1.740,00 €
14
2020013743
76543210X
1.500,00 €
Listado pág. 1/49
Puede verificar lsldldkkdkkf dkkdkdkdkkd https://www.dkkdkdkdkkdkdk.com

----
15
2020019759
76543210L
1.500,00 €

etc...

hasta

Listado pág. 49/49
Puede verificar lsldldkkdkkf dkkdkdkdkkd https://www.dkkdkdkdkkdkdk.com


texto legal... etc... etc

----
```

El código que he intentado es el siguiente pero aunque no me da errores tampoco extrae la información que quiero

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

import re

patron = '([0-9]{8})([A-Z]{1})'

input_path = "con.txt"
output_path = "nif.txt"
with open(input_path, "r") as in_file,\
open(output_path, "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        lista = re.findall(patron, line)
    if lista:
        print(lista)
    else:
        print('zer0 nif')
        out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es un nif?

Comment: @Gabitohh Numero de Identificación Fiscal. Documento de identificación en España.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es de anidamiento. El programa original dice:

```
for line in in_file:
    lista = re.findall(patron, line)
if lista:
    print(lista)
else:
    print('zer0 nif')
    out_file.write(line)
```

lo que se lee así:

> Leer todo el archivo, colocando en `lista` el resultado de la búsqueda
> con expresión regular. Al terminar el `for`, `lista` contiene el resultado
> de la expresión regular aplicada a la última línea del archivo de
> entrada.

No es lo que queremos. Queremos que se examine cada línea del archivo. Entonces, anidamos correctamente:

```
for line in in_file:
    lista = re.findall(patron, line)
    if lista:
        print(lista)
    else:
        print('zer0 nif')
        out_file.write(line)
```

Ahora `lista` se revisa e imprime con cada linea del archivo de entrada.

Comment: también tenía mal colocado out_file.write(line)... lo he puesto if lista: print(lista) out_file.write(line) y ya está perfecto... gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tienes el contenido en un fichero llamado 'dni.txt':

Podemos usar la siguiente expresión regular:

- Sabemos que pueden ser caracteres del 0 al 9 y que son 8 números. Posteriormente una letra

```
^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$
```

Con lo que el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
import re
nombreFichero = 'dni.txt'

nifRegex = "^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$"
r = re.compile(nifRegex)

# Abrimos el fichero, leemos las líneas, eliminamos espacios y lo almacenamos en una lista

with open(nombreFichero) as f:
    contenido = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]

# Filtramos usando la regex la lista anterior
listaDNI = list(filter(r.match, contenido))
```

Si hacemos un print del contenido de `listaDNI`:

```
['01234567N', '76543210Y', '01234567T', '01234567A', '01234567Q', '76543210B', '76543210Y', '76543210D', '76543210E', '76543210W', '76543210Z', '76543210S', '76543210K', '76543210X', '76543210L']
```